# Run same spider under multiple shell, will it be faster?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

For example, I have a spider that crawls some phone information from a website.

Normally, I would simply open a cmd and run the script.

So will this script take all the computer resources to run the script (CPU, Internet bandwidth)? I mean, I was asked by a colleague, "Will it be faster if I open several cmd and run the same script?".

---

So **under 1 PC**, `1 cmd + 1 spiderA` vs `several *（1 cmd + 1 spiderA)`, will the latter be faster, or the latter operation is unnecessary?

Another analogy (if description above is still not clear):

let's say a PC has 100% resource.

if `1 cmd + 1 spiderA` only takes up 20%, then `2* (1 cmd + 1 spiderA)`, will the latter combination take up 40% or divide into 10% each?

The goal of asking this is want to make sure the spider can use all the resources of 1 PC.

Comment: I was torn between downvoting or answering "YES". Chose the downvote, sorry. Apart from your question being too vague to get an exact answer, have you simply tested whether running it in parallel has a negative impact on the processing speed?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the bottleneck of the crawl is the bandwidth/latency and you will gain nothing by running multiple instance of the same spider over the same connection as scrapy is already concurrent and will take up as many connections as configured to (CONCURRENT_REQUESTS and such). Multithreading/multiprocessing might become beneficial if you are crawling a fair amount from cache for example and the non io bound code (html parsing and such) becomes tighter, but generally I'd say this would be a premature optimization.